# jenkins pipeline stuck on step ChannelClosedException

Tags: jenkins, groovy, pipeline

i'm trying to solve the issue that the connection between the master and the slave break and want the test to continue to the next bat command automatically.
the master and slave are windows machines.
and i do not want the pipeline to get stuck at the bat command if exception occurs.

the error log

> Cannot contact xxxx: hudson.remoting.ChannelClosedException: Channel
> "hudson.remoting.Channel@280d9c94:JNLP4-connect connection from
> some-ip:51478": Remote call on JNLP4-connect connection from
> some-ip:51478 failed. The channel is closing down or has closed down

my pipeline code is

```
pipeline {  
    agent { node 'master' }
    stages {   
        stage ("Run my Code") {  
            steps {               
                script {
                    def suite_script = env.SCRIPT.tokenize('\n');
                    int intNum1 =0;
                    int counter =0 ;
                    suite_script.each { item ->
                        try{
                            def tmp_suite = item.trim().tokenize(','); 
                            intNum1 += tmp_suite[2] as int
                            }catch(err){
                                print err
                            }
                        }
                    suite_script.each { item ->
                        println item
                        //get 4 parameters
                        //suite,script,amount,yes/no
                        def tmp_suite = item.trim().tokenize(',');
                        if(tmp_suite[3] == 'yes'){
                            int intNum = tmp_suite[2] as int
                            for (i = 0; i < intNum; i++) {
                                try{
                                    node("${SOME_MACHINE}"){
                                        counter++;
                                        bat 'some code with parameters  --value1 tmp_suite[0] --value2 tmp_suite[1]'
                                     }
                                }catch(err){
                                    print err
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }            

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like an agent is not configured well. It's not bat throwing error. Try to move try-catch inside node. Try to use catchError instead of try-catch

Comment: will try @daggett

Comment: for now look good, i will check it again and notify tomorrow @daggett